# Hibernate loader spending a lot of time in System.identityHashCode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using `ScrollableResults` in Hibernate and iterating through millions of records. It's taking quite a bit of time, so I did some profiling with YourKit to try and figure out how we can make this iteration faster. I expected the time to be mostly spent in either fetching from Oracle, or hydrating objects... but to my surprise, it seems to be spending a large chunk of time calling `System.identityHashCode`.

Pertinent part of the profile:

[image: ScrollableResults.next() Profile]

There are 3 major things that seem to be taking time here:

1. `T4CPreparedStatement.fetch` - This is fetching from Oracle, about 13% of the time spent.
2. `AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate` - This is creating the objects from the `ResultSet`. Quite large, but I think I can mitigate a lot of this via other means. About 29% of the time.
3. `EntityEntryContext.addEntityEntry` - This is where I have no clue how to improve because it's all spent in `System.identityHashCode`. It's 58% of the execution time.

I will note that this is quite an old version of Hibernate: 4.3.11, along with the elder JDK 8.

My `ScrollableResults` are being created this way:

```
CriteriaQuery query = ...;
ScrollableResults results = entityManager.createQuery(query)
    .unwrap(Query.class)
    .setReadOnly(true)
    .setFetchSize(20000)
    .setCacheable(false)
    .scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
```

So, a couple questions:

- Is there a way to avoid `StatefulPersistenceContext.addEntity` at all? We're not modifying any of these entities being returned, it's purely read-only, so I'm not sure why we need a persistent context... though I admit, my knowledge of the internals of Hibernate is severely lacking.
- Is there a way to speed up `System.identityHashCode`? The object has a lot of properties, mostly Strings and floats, but there are two `LocalDate` properties as well. Part of improving the object hydration will be changing from `LocalDate` to `Integer`... would that help? Unfortunately, YourKit isn't allowing me to drill further there (probably because it's a `native` method), so I've no idea.

Any insight is much appreciated!